# How to add more colors to elementor´s image carousel

Tags: css, image, carousel, elementor

I would like to ask you for help. I´m building wp site with elementor (I don´t know how to code) and I would like to add different colors to image borders or to text of the image captions. Support won´t help me with css...

I can change border color of all images in carousel with

**`selector img { border: 5px solid red; }`**

but I would like to add 6 images with 6 different color borders or with different colors of the captions of the images. (no idea what css to use)

There is written this under custom css tab:

Use "selector" to target wrapper element. Examples:

```
selector {color: red;} // For main element
selector .child-element {margin: 10px;} // For child element
.my-class {text-align: center;} // Or use any custom selector
```

Thank you

Garik

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways this can be done, but selector isn't a real element so it may be hard to pinpoint exactly what is needed. For instance, the selector would have to be an HTML element like div.

You can:
1: look for the IDs for those images (#my-id)
or
2: look for specific class names (.my-class, the . signifies that it's a class) for those images (if they are there)
3: use the pseudo-selector like first-child, last-child, nth-child

Let's look at the second option since that's closer to best practice:

1. you'll want a general CSS rule like the selector image one, but we won't have the color on it.

```
div img { border: 5px solid; }

// Below would be better because the above looks at ALL images in a div tag ... So that can turn into ... all images on a page.

.container-class-name img { border: 5px solid; }
```

All images in a div will have a solid border of 5px. It'll default to black without the next part.

2. Now the individual images. Let's say each has a class with image-{number}, so those classes would be like image-one, image-two, etc.

```
.image-one { border-color: red; }
.image-two { border-color: blue; }
.image-three { border-color: yellow; }
```

Hex color codes are better than using browser ones like red, blue, yellow and etc. If you don't know what those are I would highly suggest reading up on them.

You have to be both very general and specific when it comes to CSS and learn where each idea needs to be used.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. Borders appear only with "selector img". I would like to use it like img1,img2,img3 thats correct but this code is not working.

Comment: I found class. When I use selector .swiper-slide-image { border: 5px solid red; } it adds borders to all images. Class is doing the same as if I use selector img. Problem is I don´t know how to select directly first, second, third...image in the class with css.

Comment: Support help me this one is working if somebody wants to add borders to basic gallery .gallery-item:nth-child(1) img { border:5px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(153 204 255); }